# Mount Linux Drive in Two Places

Tags: linux, mount, hard-drive

I've been looking for a way to mount the same drive (e.g. /dev/sdd1) in two places on a hard drive. If I try using the command that I use to mount a drive in the first location again, I recieve the error:

"Mount is denied because the NTFS drive is already exclusively opened."

I've also tried binding the mount point, but obviously if the main location becomes unmounted, the binded folder becomes in accessible.

Are there any other commands I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can see of solving this problem (the "what happens if it got unmounted?" part in particular) is to use automount *and* symlinks, as suggested in Gustav's answer:

```
ln -s /mnt/original /home/max/newlink
```

The trick though would be to make `/mnt` and in particular `/mnt/original` be covered by an [automount map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter), your distribution should provide a package for this, you'll need something like the following in `/etc/auto.master`:

```
/mnt    /etc/auto.mnt
```

and then in `/etc/auto.mnt`:

```
original        -fstype=ntfs    /dev/sdd1
```

In this way accessing /mnt/original will cause `/dev/sdd1` to be mounted appropriately, but "looking through" the symlink will also cause it to be mounted if not already mounted for any reason.

(One more thing - if you happen to export this through samba too, you'll need to use `preexec` to make samba believe it existed. I was "the chatty friend" in [this blog post](http://wildebeestplain.blogspot.com/2011/10/fixing-samba-failing-to-find-canonical.html))

Answer (score 13):

With Linux *bind* mounts, there is *no such thing* as "main location". Both mounts are equal; if one is unmounted, the other will remain.

```
mount --bind /mnt/original /home/max/newlink
```

(For *fstab*, use `/mnt/original /home/max/newlink none bind`.)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a symbolic link to the second place from the first mount:

```
ln -s /mnt/original /home/max/newlink
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the (unsolvable) "if the main location becomes unmounted..." problem

Comment: So... my solution doesn't solve an unsolvable problem. A conundrum wrapped in a mystery indeed.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, regardless. I wasn't aware if this was an unsolveable issue or not. Thanks!

Comment: @GustavBertram - a comment acknowledging that would be appropriate. (The other possible solution would be to use automount on the original mount point to ensure it gets re-mounted if it has been unmounted)

Comment: @awoodland Post an answer, post an answer! (I had no idea it was unsolvable. Taking your word for it. Explication required for teh vote uppedness!)